# Unable to save DICOM from PACS using fodicom

Tags: c#, fo-dicom

I'm working with the QueryRetrieve SCU project in the FoDicom sample solution...

[FoDicom Samples](https://github.com/fo-dicom/fo-dicom-samples)

The code never hits the SaveImage method. I'm querying [www.dicomserver.co.uk](https://www.dicomserver.co.uk/) for sample images...I'm new to this and at a loss. What am I missing?

```
            var client = DicomClientFactory.Create(_qrServerHost, _qrServerPort, false, _aet, _qrServerAET);
        client.NegotiateAsyncOps();

        // Find a list of Studies

        var request = CreateStudyRequestByPatientName("Cooper");

        var studyUids = new List<string>();
        request.OnResponseReceived += (req, response) =>
        {
            studyUids.Add(response.Dataset?.GetSingleValue<string>(DicomTag.StudyInstanceUID));
        };
        await client.AddRequestAsync(request);
        await client.SendAsync();

        // find all series from a study that previous was returned
        var studyUID = studyUids[0];
        request = CreateSeriesRequestByStudyUID(studyUID);

        var serieUids = new List<string>();
        request.OnResponseReceived += (req, response) =>
        {
            serieUids.Add(response.Dataset?.GetSingleValue<string>(DicomTag.SeriesInstanceUID));
        };
        await client.AddRequestAsync(request);
        await client.SendAsync();

        // now get all the images of a serie with cGet in the same association

        client = DicomClientFactory.Create(_qrServerHost, _qrServerPort, false, _aet, _qrServerAET);

        var cGetRequest = CreateCGetBySeriesUID(studyUID, serieUids.First());
        client.OnCStoreRequest += (DicomCStoreRequest req) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " recived");
            SaveImage(req.Dataset);
            return Task.FromResult(new DicomCStoreResponse(req, DicomStatus.Success));
        };

        // the client has to accept storage of the images. We know that the requested images are of SOP class Secondary capture, 
        // so we add the Secondary capture to the additional presentation context
        // a more general approach would be to mace a cfind-request on image level and to read a list of distinct SOP classes of all
        // the images. these SOP classes shall be added here.
        var pcs = DicomPresentationContext.GetScpRolePresentationContextsFromStorageUids(
            DicomStorageCategory.Image,
            DicomTransferSyntax.ExplicitVRLittleEndian,
            DicomTransferSyntax.ImplicitVRLittleEndian,
            DicomTransferSyntax.ImplicitVRBigEndian);
        client.AdditionalPresentationContexts.AddRange(pcs);
        await client.AddRequestAsync(cGetRequest);
        await client.SendAsync();
```

Comment: when did you execute this sample? The Dicomserver provides the server logs on this site: https://dicomserver.co.uk/logs/. I was looking there to find the log with a query for Patient "Cooper" but did not find it.
The code looks fine, so I need some logging in order to help you

Comment: i just ran it 10/13/2021 830am Eastern Standard time. The link to the log is below. 

https://dicomserver.co.uk/logs/D.O.Net.20211013.130000.80014.0.log

my ae title is DICOMSAMURAI

Comment: I can see the cfind request by patientname and then I can see the cfind request for series by studyinstanceuid. But then no further connection is done.
What does your full code look like? you cut it off after adding the eventhandler on the client. Did you add the cGetRequest to the client and call client.SendAsync() ? did you add the additional presentation states?

Comment: btw: the code from the sample is just to demonstrate how it works. Usually you would call a cFind on studies by Patientname and then immediatelly call a cGet by studyinstanceuid to receive the whole study instead of first calling the cFind for series-information

Comment: yeah im stupid. i disabled part of the code i needed. i added the piece of code i needed it starts... // the client has to accept storage of the images.... i appreciate the help!

Comment: now i can see the log entries on dicomserver.co.uk/logs. There everything looks fine. Do you now get the SaveImage method invoked?

Comment: yes everything works now!

Answer (score 2):

i disabled part of the code i needed. i added the piece of code i needed it starts... // the client has to accept storage of the images....

Comment: Please, make your answer more clear and informative. This will help a lot the community.